# Why would renormalization be necessary without divergent integrals?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, s-matrix-theory

Weinberg uses the LSZ reduction formula to introduce field renormalization,and on page 441, he says:

> As this discussion should make clear: the renormalization of masses and fields has nothing to do with the presence of infinities, and would be necessary even in a theory in which all momentum space integrals were convergent.

I believe weinberg is right , but I can't convince other people: how is renormaliztion needed without infinities?
 What does it have to do with the LSZ formula?
I want answers to make clear the field renormalization with LSZ reduction formula. so maybe the question is different , because I am asking weinberg's book.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is renormalization necessary in finite theories?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/74467/) (nice question by the way, +1).

Comment: Great question, I'd like to hear more answers/perspectives on this, but it is indeed a duplicate

Comment: Actually, I'm not convinced by the answer given in the other post. I'd vote to leave this open even if it's a duplicate.